# When using select() function to select columns from a dataframe by name in R, I got NAs

Tags: r, select

[this the original dataset "hk"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNrOE.png)

select(hk,date,new_cases) ["new_cases" lied in the third column in the dataset. It's strange that it showed an error of "'new_cases' not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNsAg.png)

a <- select(hk,new_cases)[Then, I tried select one variable. But I failed to draw it. The new dataset was the same as the original dataset after selecting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cntkB.png)

select(hk,date)[When picking up the "date" variable, it returned NAs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgGZu.png)

I'm down as I couldn't figure out where  problems are.

Comment: probably you're not using the select function you think you're using. print `select`  and see what namespace is indicated, 'MASS' maybe ? Make sure to attach dplyr or tidyverse last, or use the conflicted package

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints. It's a good start to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.